# Installing php-fpm apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, centos7

I am trying to use php-fpm as I have heard it can increase performance on my webserver, and it appears to be working.. but it doesn't look like it has speeded anything up.

I ran through the following steps.

- Installed php-fpm using yum
- Configured the php-fpm to use a unix socket and set the [www] listen to apache
- Renamed 10-php.conf to 10-php.conf.disabled
- Switched mpm from mpm_prefork_module to mpm_event_module
- Added the following to all my vhosts underneath the Directory setting:

  ```
  # php-fpm
  <FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://www/"
  </FilesMatch>
  ```
- Restarted/Started everything and enabled php-fpm on boot

I was a bit confused about mod_fcgi, mod_fastcgi and mod_php but haven't changed any of these (other than renaming 10-php.conf). I read something about mod_proxy_fcgi being the modern standard but again haven't explicitly installed or enabled it.

Is this the correct setup, or am I missing something to get any benefit?

Answer (score 1):

*This solution doesn't use UNIX sockets (it listens on port 9000), but I give this answer for others who may be looking for a means to install PHP7-FPM on CentOS in an easy manner.*

**Step 1: Set Up PHP-FPM Daemon**

Configure your [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php70/) repository, then:

```
yum install rh-php70 rh-php70-php-fpm
systemctl enable rh-php70-php-fpm
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start rh-php70-php-fpm
```

- Config is under `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php70`
- Logs are under `/var/opt/rh/rh-php70/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`
- systemd links `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rh-php70-php-fpm.service` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rh-php70-php-fpm.service`
- The executable lives at `/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm`

**Step 2: Configure Apache FastCGI**

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/$1
```

[Further reading](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM).

Answer (score 0):

If you are optimizing anything you should have a metric you're looking at.
Make some measurement, there're a lot of tools for that, like [`ab`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html), [`siege`](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege). [`jmeter`](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Get some results and compare different configuration to see which one is better for you.

Comment: I was looking at response time and possibly memory use, neither of which showed any obvious improvement.. I was asking in case I missed a part of the set-up.

Answer (score -2):

Please have a look in php-fpm config directory where you need to optimize according to your server resource checkout your configuration.
   Reerence:
https://serversforhackers.com/video/php-fpm-process-management
http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php